# How do I modify my code to compare the user input against "QUIT" and have it exit the loop if they don't match?

Tags: assembly, lc3

When I run my program, it is supposed to go through the rest of my code when I type anything but QUIT, but when I type anything, it just HALTS my program.

This question is the same project that I'm working on, but at a different stage-[text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77616208/23049636)

I have tried modifying my code as to the order it executes, but it doesn't help. I have gone through the debugger, but can't identify the exact problem.

Here is my code for this specfic loop, for reference:

```
; String compare function
    STRING_COMPARE_QUIT AND R0, R0, #0 ; Initialize result to 0
        ; R1 points to 'QUIT', R2 to INPUT_BUFFER
        ; R3/R4 are characters from the strings
        ; R5 is a comparison flag, R6 for lowercase checking
        ; R6 is the lowercase mask
        CASE_INSENSITIVE_COMPARE_QUIT
            LEA   R1, QUIT           ; Point to the string "QUIT"
            LD    R2, INPUT_BUFFER   ; Point to the input buffer
            AND   R5, R5, #0         ; Clear the comparison flag

            CHECK_LOOP_QUIT
                LDR   R3, R1, #0         ; Load character from "QUIT"
                LDR   R4, R2, #0         ; Load character from input buffer

                ; Check if R3 is lowercase and convert it to uppercase if it is
                LD    R6, MASK     ; Load the lowercase mask value into R6
                AND   R6, R3, R6         ; Mask off bits with R6 to check if it's a lowercase letter
                BRz   NOT_LOWERCASE_1_QUIT    ; Zero flag means it's not a lowercase letter
                ADD   R3, R3, #0         ; Make sure condition codes are set based on R3
                BRn   NOT_LOWERCASE_1_QUIT    ; Negative flag means it's not a lowercase letter (ASCII < 'a')
                BRzp  CASE_CHECK_R3_QUIT      ; Zero or positive means we have a lowercase letter
                NOT_LOWERCASE_1_QUIT
                BRnzp SKIP_CONVERSION_1_QUIT  ; Skip conversion if not lowercase
                
                CASE_CHECK_R3_QUIT
                    LD    R6, MASK           ; Load the value 32 into R6 from memory
                    AND   R6, R3, R6         ; Apply mask with R6 to check if R3's character is lowercase
                    BRz   CONVERT_R3_QUIT         ; If zero, convert this lowercase to uppercase
                    ; This label is no longer needed since BRnzp is unconditional here and
                    ; we don't have any instructions in between
                    SKIP_CONVERSION_1_QUIT    ; This line should be removed eventually, unless you have more code to add here.
                    BRnzp NEXT_INSTRUCTION_QUIT   ; Always jump to the next instructionstruction if no conversion needed
                    CONVERT_R3_QUIT
                        LD   R6, TO_UPPERCASE  ; Load the value 32 into R6
                        NOT  R3, R3            ; Invert R3 to prepare for addition
                        ADD  R3, R3, #1        ; Add 1 to complete 2's complement negation
                        ADD  R3, R3, R6        ; Add R6 (which is 32) to complete the subtraction, effectively converting lowercase to uppercase
                    NEXT_INSTRUCTION_QUIT
                    ; Check if R4 is lowercase and convert it to uppercase if it is
                    LD    R6, MASK ;
                    AND   R6, R4, R6     ; Mask off bits to check if it's a lowercase letter
                    BRz   NOT_LOWERCASE_2_QUIT    ; Zero flag means it's not a lowercase letter
                    ADD   R4, R4, #0         ; Make sure condition codes are set based on R4
                    BRn   NOT_LOWERCASE_2_QUIT    ; Negative flag means it's not a lowercase letter (ASCII < 'a')
                    BRzp  CASE_CHECK_R4      ; Zero or positive means we have a lowercase letter
                    NOT_LOWERCASE_2_QUIT
                    BRnzp SKIP_CONVERSION_2_QUIT  ; Skip conversion if not lowercase
                CASE_CHECK_R4_QUIT
                    LD    R6, MASK
                    AND   R6, R4, R6
                    BRz CONVERT_R4_QUIT
                    SKIP_CONVERSION_2_QUIT
                    BRnzp NEXT_INSTRUCTION_FOR_R4_QUIT
                    CONVERT_R4_QUIT
                    LD   R6, TO_UPPERCASE
                    NOT R4, R4
                    ADD R3, R3, #1
                    ADD   R4, R4, R6      ; Convert lowercase to uppercase by adding binary 0010000
                    ; Continue on with the processing of R4
                    NEXT_INSTRUCTION_FOR_R4_QUIT
                ADD R6, R3, #0  ; Update flags based on R3 value
                BRz   CHECK_QUIT_END   ; If R3 is NULL, go check input buffer end
                ADD   R6, R4, #0         ; Update flags based on R4 value
                BRz   STRINGS_NOT_EQUAL_QUIT ; If R4 is NULL here, it's a mismatch
                ; No NULL is encountered, so compare the characters
                CHAR_EQUAL_QUIT
                    ADD   R1, R1, #1         ; Increment to the next character of "QUIT"
                    ADD   R2, R2, #1         ; Increment to the next character of the input buffer
                    BRnzp CHECK_LOOP         ; Continue the loop
                CONTINUE_COMPARE_QUIT
                    ADD   R1, R1, #1       ; Move to the next character in "QUIT"
                    ADD   R2, R2, #1       ; Move to the next character in input buffer
                    BRnzp CHECK_LOOP_QUIT       ; Loop back
                CHECK_QUIT_END
                    ADD   R6, R4, #0       ; Copy R4 to check if input also ends
                    BRz   STRINGS_ARE_EQUAL_QUIT  ; If R4 is NULL, both strings end here, thus are equal
                    BRnzp STRINGS_NOT_EQUAL_QUIT  ; If R4 is not NULL, mismatch
                STRINGS_NOT_EQUAL_QUIT
                    BRnzp STRING_COMPARE_QUIT_EXIT

                STRINGS_ARE_EQUAL_QUIT
                    ; Set flag for "equal", Input matches "QUIT" (case insensitive)
                    AND   R5, R5, #0       ; Clear R5
                    ADD   R5, R5, #1       ; Set R5 to indicate strings are equal
                    BRzp EXIT
        STRING_COMPARE_QUIT_EXIT
```

Comment: Dies `INPUT_BUFFER` contain the buffer, or does it contain the ADDRESS of the buffer?  Your code assumes it contains an address.

Comment: That's a lot of code, too much, yet not enough to reproduce, though.  Still, looks like you're upper/lowercasing both, when usually would only upper/lower the user input and the other would already be so.

Comment: Suggest doing a C or other language version, then following along both to see where one goes wrong.  The idea is not about modifying this code to do the right thing, but knowing what the right way such code should work, algorithmically,  regardless of assembly or C or other.

Comment: @TimRoberts The INPUT_BUFFER is a label for storing user input, it is an address.

Comment: @ErikEidt I can give you the rest of my code, I put in the specific function that was causing me problems

Comment: Well, think you might debug it some first.